# How to unstick water-damaged pages of a book

Tags: water, books

Some liquid (possibly juice) was in my bag for a week, which caused my textbook to get wet from the top. The pages are now dry but stuck together. Could anyone please explain how to separate the pages without damaging them?

Comment: Related: [Easy way to remove the sticky pages of a book caused by being wet?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/3843/12517)

Answer (score 2):

put it in the microwave for a bit then clean the damaged area with some clean towel and try gently to separate them repeat 'till fixed
beware i might be wrong this worked for me once i don't know your full case 
Good luck !

Comment: This looks the method when the book is still wet. I do not think a dried book will do well in the microwave.

Answer (score 1):

Steam. Hold your book over a boiling pot of water, so as the steam goes to where the pages are stuck. The less stuck pages separate themselves. Gently separate the pages if you can. Don't hold the book over the steam long enough to get it wet again. If the pages don't come apart hold the book over steam again. It took me almost 10 minutes to steam  296 pages. No damage was done to the book.

Comment: If you try this, be very wary of this creating mold.  Books are notorious for acting as mold substrates, and trust me, most molds are ***not*** healthy to have around.